# Could not find a declaration file for module ‘Set/ajaxHoc.jsx’ when I use the baseurl and path to import a custom module I create

Tags: typescript

In a.tsx I'm trying to import a module I create in ajaxHoc.jsx in another folder, so I set baseUrl and paths in tsconfig.json, but VScode reports an error "TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'Set/ajaxHoc'. 'D:\xxx\project\src\code\set\ajaxHoc.jsx' implicitly has an 'any' type." I'm sure the path of module is right and `require` is OK. How can I solve this problem if I want to use `import`?

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./project/src",
    "paths": {
        "Set/*": ["code/set/*"], 
    }, 
}

// a.tsx
import ajaxHoc from 'Set/ajaxHoc'; // Error
const { default : ajaxHoc}= require('Set/ajaxHoc');  // OK
```

Comment: it looks like path is right, but u try to import js file with no declaration in ts. you should have d.ts file associated with this module

Comment: @JurajKocan I added `declare module 'ajaxHoc';` in ajaxHoc.d.ts but got the error "File 'D:/XXXX/project/src/code/set/ajaxHoc.d.ts' is not a module."

Comment: @JurajKocan Adding `export default ajaxHoc` after `declare` does work, thanks.